# Получение списка открытых именованных дескрипторов процесса

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Собственно задача ясна из названия, мне необходимо вывести на экран список открытых именованных дескрипторов процесса (по PID), их тип и имя. Все что я смог найти в интернете, это NtQuerySystemInformation, но во всех примерах использовалась какая-то устаревшая реализация, которая принимала совсем другие параметры. К тому же, насколько я понял, это недокументированная функция, что тоже не очень здорово. Есть ли какой-то другой способ сделать то, что мне нужно?

Comment: NtQuerySystemInformation вообще описана в MSDN